# How to book courier flights (discounted fare in exchange for delivering a package upon arrival)?

Tags: budget, air-travel

I've heard people talking about courier flights; cheap fares that can be obtained in exchange for carrying a package from one place to another on behalf of a company or benefactor. Do these flights still exist, and where can they be found?

Comment: As I understood from article, this is option only for US, isn't it?

Comment: 10 or 20 years ago when I first read about them they weren't just in the US. But I haven't heard about them for a while now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found [this article](http://budgettravel.about.com/cs/aircouriers/a/mission_courier.htm) about courier flights. It says that this option is less popular and hard to find than 10 years ago because of air-deliver industry grows from that time.

> Unlike the late 1990s and early 2000s, when these flights became popular, air cargo companies now have much larger fleets and more sophisticated handling services that work with customs agencies to speed deliveries.

Also there is many security restrictions after 9/11 event, so you can be in trouble because you don't know what exactly you have in your bag.

Comment: Perhaps they make an exception if the courier package is a volleyball that you've named 'Wilson' in a fit of emotion.

Comment: @Ankur and that the carrier name is FedEx

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee Didn't get the joke, if any.

Comment: @VMAtm it was a reference to the movie *[Cast Away](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0162222/)* with Tom Hanks.

Comment: @Spredzy Oh. I'll watch it then :)